# Download files from Sharepoint Document Library using Sharepoint Web Service

Tags: sharepoint, ssis

We got document library in SharePoint 2010 holding multiple documents.

I'm struggling to write the code in SSIS - using script component through which we can download those documents using SHAREPOINT web service.

Comment: What does "struggling" mean? Do you have some code and/or error messages that you can show? Have you followed the [tutorial](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/) for using SSIS with SharePoint?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score -1):

You can simply access the files directly using an http URL.  From your library choose Library / Open with Explorer.  This will show you the URL to use.